# Java - For Each Derived class in a Collection of Base classes

Tags: java, collections, for-loop, each

I have successfully done this with Visual Basic, I just want to know if there is a simple way to do this with Java.

I want a For loop that will iterate through Derived classes from a Base class Collection.

```
public class Game{
    private Collection<GameEntity> entities;

    // Methods would go here to control GameEntity's

    private abstract class GameEntity{
        protected Game owner; //Defines which instance Game owns this Entity

        public GameEntity(Game owner) {
            this.owner=owner;
        }

        public abstract void tick();
    }

    private class Partical extends GameEntity{
        public Partical(Game owner) {
            super(owner);
        }

        public void tick(){
            for (Partical p : owner.entities) { //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
                if(p != this){ //Don't do physics with itself

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alright so here I have my Game class that has a Collection of GameEntity's but GameEntity is strickly a Base class.

Partical is derived from the GameEntity class.

What I want the for loop to do is iterate through the Collection of GameEntity's and pick out all the Partical classes from Collection.

Where my problem is I get an "Incompatible Types" error. I do realize they are different types.

Comment: You know of `instanceof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 for(GameEntity entity : owner.entities) {
      if(entity instanceof Partical) {
          Partical partical = (Partical) entity;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to iterate & check for the desired class types:

```
for (GameEntity e : owner.entities) { //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    if (e instanceof Partical) {
        Partical p = (Partical)e;
        if(p != this){ //Don't do physics with itself
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has a type checking, you can use instanceOf to check if a type is instance of some other super type, for example:

```
 if(entity instanceOf Partical) {
   // do smth
 }
```